# How should I Turn an Animated Gif Trasparent?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation, gif

I have an animated GIF with a background color. I needed to remove the background for one of my works, so I just deleted background for all 250 layers with the magic eraser!

When I run the animation in PhotoShop it's okay, but when I render it (save for web) it turns into this awkward thing. I really have no clue why this happens since I'm not that pro using graphics.

Here are my `.gif`s
https://www.dropbox.com/s/8je74x1t0zlxbs3/ls2.gif?dl=0 and https://www.dropbox.com/s/3gcjhtk1evvoab4/giff111111.gif?dl=0

Any help, such as making the GIF transparent by other means, is welcome

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

That is called a halo.

[image: Halo on a gif image]

This is becouse gif can make transparent only one verey specific colour, not all the intermediate colours that make that small gradient.

And you have no other option on a gif file. The one thing you can do is make another version starting with the white background. A Light background version and a dark background version.

You can try other modern techniques like a sprite css background with transparent png files.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp